# Long title in Jquery's plugin FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have a little problem with long title in fullcalendar plugin. If u have a long title and short event time (for example 1 day) so ur event title will not to be fit.

What I can do with that?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to show the title in multiple lines, you can override the fullcalendar default CSS.

**Default CSS in FullCalendar v2.1.1**

```
.fc-day-grid-event > .fc-content {
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Remove the `white-space: nowrap;` and yout title will always be visible.

Answer (score 3):

Give this a shot:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    var limit = 20;
    if (event.title.length > limit) {
        element.find('.fc-event-title').text(event.title.substr(0,limit)+'...').parent().attr('title', event.title);
    }
}
```

That will crop and add a title with native browser tooltips.  you could use qtip if you wanted

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    var limit = 20;
    if (event.title.length > limit) {
        element.find('.fc-event-title').text(event.title.substr(0,limit)+'...');
        element.qtip({
            // qtip options here
        });
    }
}
```

Use qtip2 as qtip1 will break with jQuery 1.9+ [info here](http://qtip2.com/)

Comment: just an update, need to find div class `.fc-title` in `FullCalendar v2.9.1`

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it like this for MonthView:

Find this function: (for me it's on line#5381)

```
function daySegHTML(segs)
```

In this function find this code:

```
html +=
     " class='" + classes.join(' ') + "'" +
     " style='position:absolute;z-index:8;left:"+left+"px;" + skinCss + "'" +
```

Add a piece of code before this, so it should look like this:

```
if(event.title.length > 10)
    var eventShortTitle = event.title.substring(0,10) + '...';
else
    var eventShortTitle = event.title;

html +=
     " class='" + classes.join(' ') + "'" +
     " style='position:absolute;z-index:8;left:"+left+"px;" + skinCss + "'" +
```

Then a few lines bellow find this code:

```
"<span class='fc-event-title'>" + htmlEscape(event.title) + "</span>" +
```

Replace it with this:

```
"<span class='fc-event-title'>" + htmlEscape(eventShortTitle) + "</span>" +
```

You long title issue is now fixed in Month view. You can do the same for Week and Day view.

Comment: is it easy for you to say where the code for the week and day view is located?

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou | Sorry, I worked on FullCalendar a long time ago. I don't even have the code now.

Comment: ...oh,anyway,I found where the code is located but the problem is that the same code affects both week and day view,instead I want different adjustment made for week view and different for day view...of course all these do not matter now cause as you said you are not working on full calendar anymore

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou | Only one tip, if you are working with fullCalendar, make sure that you spend enough time understanding the plugin's code. Once you'll understand it, you'll start enjoying your work with fullCalendar.

Comment: Ι have not found a way yet to distinguish between day and week view.I have to know that cause because I have to make different adjustments to day view regarding the event title length.

Comment: I found a solution after all

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou | Great (Y)

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Change the way the event is rendered, either in [eventRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) (the callback where the user may modify the div) or in the source of fullcalendar itself.
2. Add a tooltip to the calendar event that shows the full title, perhaps with [qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/).
3. Modify the size of your calendar and increment in minutes (for an agenda day of week view) so that shorter events have more space if this is a frequent issue.

Answer (score 1):

I made a little bit different thing with this problem:

Find this part in source of fullcallendar:

```
if (seg.contentTop !== undefined && height - seg.contentTop < 10) {
// not enough room for title, put it in the time header
    eventElement.find('div.fc-event-time')
    .text(formatDate(event.start, opt('timeFormat')) + ' - ' + event.title);
(...)
```

This  `if` is changing the way that short events are displayed.

I just removed the whole `if` from the source code and added `eventAfterRender` callback to my js code:

```
eventAfterRender: (function(event, element, view) {
    $(".fc-event").each(function(){
        if ($(this).height() < $(this).find('.fc-event-content').height()) {
            var fcPrevHeight = $(this).height();
            var fcSlideHeight = $(this).height() + $(this).find('.fc-event-content').height();
            $(this).hover(      
                function() {
                    $(this).css('height', fcSlideHeight)
                },
                function() {
                    $(this).css('height', fcPrevHeight);
                }
            )
        }
    })
})
```

When the event is small and you can't see the whole event title, this code is changing the height of div when the mouse is over so you can the title of the event :P

Answer (score 0):

@Arron answer works perfectly for me except for an update for version `FullCalendar v2.9.1`

need to find `div` with class `fc-title` and not `.fc-event-title`

```
var titleLimit = 20;
    if (event.title.length > titleLimit) {
        eventElement.find('.fc-title').text(event.title.substr(0,titleLimit)+'...').parent().attr('title', event.title);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant of other `eventRender` answers that applies only in month view, where titles are truncated most severely:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    var limit = 10;
    if (view.type === 'month' && event.title.length > limit) {
        element.find('.fc-title').parent().attr('title', event.title);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a break line in the event, between time and title, using the func **`eventRender`**.

It solution applies only for *month view*.

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    var limit = 10;
    if (view.type === 'month' && event.title && event.title.length > limit) {
        element.find('.fc-title')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', "<br>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Version 5.9 just set:

```
.fc-event-main{
    overflow:hidden;
}
.fc-event-title{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```